# getting the parent element text using jquery from within a js function

Tags: jquery

I would like to figure out a way to retrieve the the link text users click on from within my webapp... i'm wondering if jquery can do it.

Heres what a link would look like:

```
<span onclick="myfunction();">Link Text 1</span>
```

The function "myfunction()" is located inside a .js file that gets incluced into the page

When the user clicks on the span tag, I would like to capture the text from the span tag that called the myfunction(), then place the text "Link Text 1" into a js variable I would then use to update my database with.

I know I could do this:

```
<span onclick="var xx = $(this).text(); myfunction(xx);">Link Text 1</span>
```

But I have too many calls to this one function that rewriting the click events would be too much...i'm wondering how I can accomplish the same thing from within the "myfunction()" code using jquery to retrieve the text?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `$(this).text()` within `myfunction()`? Pretty sure it will work. Also, it's usually cleaner and easier to use something like `<span class="myFuncOnClick">Link Text 1</span>` and `$('.myFuncOnClick').click(function() { /* do whatever with $(this) */ });`. Of course, you should use something semantic rather than `myFuncOnClick` for the class name...

Comment: Have you ever heard of find and replace, also wouldn't it have been easier to bind the click events with `.click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[try this:](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Zz2/)

```
<span>Link Text 1</span>
```

```
$('span').click(function(e){
   var txt = $(this).text() // gets span's text
})
```

Comment: The op never said anything about anchors

Comment: maybe: _a way to retrieve the the link text`_?

Comment: thanks...this was the only way i could implement it...calling $(this).text() from within the js function did not work...i had to bind it to the click event....to get around the global "find n replace", which is not a good idea with a large project, I used jqueries .delegate() and targeted only the ul elements like this:  $('ul#menu_nav').delegate("a", "click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault()
     var txt = $(this).text()
     alert(txt);
   })

Answer (score 0):

In the html:

```
<span onclick="myfunction(this)">Link Text 1</span>
```

Javascript function:

```
function myfunction(elem){
    var theText =$(elem).text();
}
```

Comment: In `myfunction` `this` is the window object